# Typescript create anonymous objects

Tags: typescript

I want to create a hierarchy of nested objects in typescript that looks like the following

```
snapshot{
   profile{
      data{
         firstName = 'a'
         lastName = 'aa'
      }
   }
}
```

I dont want to create a class structure, just want to create the nested hierarchy of objects thats all.

Answer (score 32):

TypeScript is just JavaScript with some extra sugar on top, so regular anonymous JavaScript objects are legal:

```
var snapshot:any = {
   profile: {
      data: {
         firstName: 'a',
         lastName: 'aa'
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but how do I specify a type of firstName?

Answer (score 1):

If you want TypeScript to enforce your anonymous object type, you can do the following.  However, I recommend using this technique sparingly.  If you have large complex objects, it will probably benefit you to call out an interface/class structure.  Otherwise, the readability of your code may suffer.

```
let snapshot: {
  profile: {
    data: {
      firstName: string;
      lastName: string;
    };
  };
};
```